# Excel VBA Update/Replace Vlookup file Name

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

How can I change entire Workbook Vlookup formula file name.

I have a formula in column B of

```
=vlookup(A1,'[report_**123120**.xlsx]ABC_sheet_**123120**'$A:$C,3,0) - vlookup(A1,'[report_**123120**.xlsx]ABC_sheet_**121420**'$A:$C,3,0)
```

I need to update the file above name by changing all **123120** to **013121**; and **121420** to **011521**,

```
=vlookup(A1,'[report_013121.xlsx]ABC_sheet_013121'$A:$C,3,0) - vlookup(A1,'[report_013121.xlsx]ABC_sheet_011521'$A:$C,3,0)
```

Is there a way I can update this use VBA? or if there is an easy way without VBA works too.

**The find and replace function doesn't work because the name "ABC_sheet_121420" is not in "report_013121.xlsx".**

Comment: `Range("B1").Formula = "=VLookup(A1,'[report_" & VARIABLE_HERE & ".xlsx]"` - etc...

Comment: The Find & Replace function does work but you need to go into its `Options`. Select "Look in" `Formulas` and make sure to uncheck "Match entire cell contents" because the date you want to change is only a part of it.

Comment: The replace and find doesn't work. If I changed all 123120 to 013121, then it will ask me it cannot find "ABC_sheet_121420"